# Why is my AWS S3 object not getting deleted?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using php code to delete s3 object.

```
 echo "filename :".$filename;
        echo "bucket :".BUCKET;

        $this->s3->deleteObject(BUCKET, $filename);
        exit;

filename :4d51361e0b735.jpgbucket :mybucketname
```

Why is my s3 object not getting deleted?

### Update

After checking I found that in s3fox file is getting deleted but if I see the image in browser by url it is still showing. Why is this?

Comment: Please provide more context. What framework are you using? Are you getting error messages? What is the context of the code? This question is unanswerable in the current form.

Comment: @Aron M not using any framework , m using simple s3 class , no error message

Comment: still, please provide more info and edit your question accordingly. People can't (and should not) guess what class you are using. Providing more info will help us to answer your question.

Comment: @all Strange! if i am seeing in s3fox file is getting deleted but if i see the image in browser by url it is still showing how ?

Comment: @all no i think its not cache issue because i open in other browser after deletion and it is opening .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is just showing up on your browser, it is probably cached. Either in the browser or at a proxy.

Try <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD-SHIFT-R</kbd> on Mac) to reload a page and skipping cache (doesn't necessarily work when it's cached at a proxy).

Comment: @all no i think its not cache issue because i open in other browser after deletion and it is opening .

Comment: then maybe its cached in the server